# New Meta site title's reputation changes indicator displays different number than in my profile view

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page

I just edited a post and earned 2 reputation. Now it is properly showing `+2` in the new title bar, but when I visited my profile it shows me following things,

> [image]

My profile page shows `+4` in the reputation tab's title while the title bar displays only `+2`. I am not saying that this is bug, but as my previous `+2` is still unvisited the new title bar should display `+4` too.

What do you think ?

Comment: I have the same thing even I don't have much reputation . I was wonder how come in meta less than there .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top bar reputation is global, your reputation tab on your profile is just for that site.

[image]
<sub>Not super obvious if you're only on one or two sites</sub>

Because they're different things, they have different "last read" checks.  This is something we may revisit later (I personally think that indicator may be superfluous after the new top bar is on everywhere [which will be after we're happy with it on meta, still plenty of tweaks to go]).

Comment: Eh, it's still nice to check things in detail. I'd like it better as it is, to be honest. More space is better, so the highlighting on the profile page is useful to check reputation changes in detail.

Comment: @Emrakul there's definitely value in the rep tab drill down, I'm not sure there will still be value in the "rep change since you last drilled down *on this site*"-indicator on that user profile tab once the new top bar is on everywhere.  I'm just pointing out that they are, currently by design, different things; they aren't meant to lineup as things are.

Comment: That's fair. I'm not too concerned about it, to be honest. It's not like it would impair the functionality of the site to link them together.